# Is there a configuration system for Python, JavaScript, and CSS?

Tags: javascript, python, css, configuration

I have a project that is mostly Python code but also contains some HTML, JavaScript, and CSS. Depending on the build-target, some things have to be configured across the source files (e.g. some values for constants).

Is there a nice tool/technique that allows me to configure Python, JavaScript, and CSS with *one* configuration file upon build time? The configurations I'm talking about are merely string substitutions and nothing fancy.

Since the project is mostly Python code, I'd probably prefer to use ini-style configuration files and [ConfigParser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html) for Python, and re-use the configuration file for the rest of the source files as well.

Comment: Puppet/Ansible/Salt let you configure multiple things using one central place. They're more "deployment" tools than build tools though and may be too heavyweight for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like [Cmake](http://cmake.org) and the [configure_file](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/configure_file.html) command come pretty close to my requirements. Together with out-of-source builds it is pretty easy to deploy different configurations in different directories. It does not use ini-stytle configuration files, though.